# morris js donut doesnt render in bootstrap tab

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, morris.js

I'm trying do display a morrisjs chart within a bootstrap tabbed page.
I'm using the sample chart here:
[Donut Chart](http://jsbin.com/ukaxod/144/embed?html,js,output)

When I place the `<div id="example-donut">` outside of the bootstrap tabs, everything works.
Once I place it inside a bootstrap tab

```
<div class="tabbable" id="tabs-936589">
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="mycharts">
      <div id="example-donut"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get the following error:

Error: Invalid value for <text> attribute transform="matrix(NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,0,0)"

If I place it in the active tab, this works without any issues.

Anyone else hitting this same issue ?

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I'm having the same issue.  Ever find a workaround?

Comment: Did someone find a resolution for this? I am facing this exact issue but for me it's a Bootstrap Carousel instead of a tab but I think it's happening for same reasons. @EatPeanutButter

Comment: My solution ultimately was moving to the highcharts library instead.  Really solid library

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```
Morris.Donut.prototype.resizeHandler = function () {
    this.timeoutId = null;
    if (this.el && this.el.width() > 0 && this.el.height() > 0) {
        this.raphael.setSize(this.el.width(), this.el.height());
        return this.redraw();
    }
    else return null;
};
Morris.Donut.prototype.setData = function (data) {
    var row;
    this.data = data;
    this.values = (function () {
        var _i, _len, _ref, _results;
        _ref = this.data;
        _results = [];
        for (_i = 0, _len = _ref.length; _i < _len; _i++) {
            row = _ref[_i];
            _results.push(parseFloat(row.value));
        }
        return _results;
    }).call(this);
    if (this.el && this.el.width() > 0 && this.el.height() > 0) {
        return this.redraw();
    }
    else return null;
};
```

Comment: Adding only `resizeHandler` helped me.