# Morris.js chart renders only on active Bootstrap tab, not other tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, morris.js

I see the following error in other tabs when trying to render morris donut charts:
`raphael-min.js:8 Error: <text> attribute transform: Expected number, "matrix(NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN,…".`
I want it to render correctly across all tabs.

1. I tried setting `resize: false` & `redraw: true`, that dint work
2. I am unable to access bootstrap-tabs in my workflow and hence do not have the option to manually make tabs active using `.tabs` or `.tab('show')`.
3. From what I understood from other posts, [morris js donut doesnt render in bootstrap tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006159/morris-js-donut-doesnt-render-in-bootstrap-tab) is close to my problem. I did not follow this solution though.
   Can anybody please help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [morris js donut doesnt render in bootstrap tab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34006159/morris-js-donut-doesnt-render-in-bootstrap-tab)

Comment: That seems to be the exact same problem. Have you looked at the issues section on github to check if others have had the same problem and if theres a solution?

Comment: If you look in the related questions section on the bottom right youll find related questions that might hold the solution like - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128708/load-morris-js-graph-in-active-tab-bootstrap?rq=1

Comment: @Craicerjack I did look at the github issues, the solutions ppl suggested did not work for me. I am suspecting I am not calling destroy() method correctly from within the morris.js plugin - hence unable to resolve.

Comment: @Craicerjack regarding the link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22128708/load-morris-js-graph-in-active-tab-bootstrap?rq=1, I cannot implement .tab('show') because my bootstrap tabs arent using bootstrap-tab.js, I did not see this event during debug, so cannot implement.